# Hiding Initialization Cells

Tags: front-end

I have seen multiple notebooks with near invisible Initialization Cells, and wish to recreate them myself (see screenshot below).

[image: Visual representation]

In the screenshot, the first Initialization Cell is expanded, contains code, can be evaluated, but you cannot see the code inside. Said cell was used to define the function "plotRotation" while hiding the code.

How would I be able to recreate this in a notebook myself? The code inside the cell is irrelevant so long as I am able to change it.

Comment: If you select the desired cell then you can do: Cell>Cell Properties>Open. Is this what you want?

Comment: You can double click the output cell to hide the input cell.

Comment: @demm Your answer is the one I was looking for - thank you!